# Javascript Confirm method Kills my session data on Safari 5.0.2

Tags: javascript, safari, confirm

There is something seriously wrong here. I am about a 100% sure the confirm method is causing serious issues with sessions on Safari. The confirm prompt basically asks the user to make sure he/she wants to go through with an action before pulling off a Jquery POST. This works fine on every other browser, but on Safari the users session data gets deleted and they get logged out upon refreshing the page. I removed the method and everything is back to normal. Has anyone experienced this before? Very strange... *shakes fist at apple*

Edit: I tried using Jqueries Dialog widget and I am experiencing the same issues. What do you think is going on?

Edit2: For those who are curious, the alert doesn't wipe out the session data, it just brings the control back to the client end therefore the browser isn't really in touch with its server side. This comment explains it best:

> You have to be mindful of where your code is running when you are
>   using ASP.NET. In your example, since you are using the Session
>   object, you are running on the server. Your web server has no way of
>   popping up an alert dialog on the user's machine. Instead, it has to
>   write JavaScript code to the client, which can then execute this code
>   and give the user an alert. So, you need to change your approach. If
>   you need the alert, you will need to feed the information to the
>   client, and have the entire check take place there, in which case you
>   lose access to your session variable (stored on the server), so the
>   only comparison you will be able to do is based on something on that
>   form or else something that you write out to the client machine.

Reference: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t65880-javascript-alert-function.html

It's ridiculous to see that Safari does not automatically handle this situation like it's counterparts.

Edit3: More proof! A quick google search revealed lots of people on Safari have complaints about getting signed out of facebook randomly. Facebook also has pop up balloon warnings that notify you about important instances such as walking away from a half written message. I get logged out every time that balloon warns me! It's like a tough bouncer for Safari. What is going on here?

Comment: The session is a server-side concept; it's only manifested in the browser by a cookie with a particular name and value. Are you saying that the `confirm()` call is clearing that cookie?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what's going on here. I will double check to see if the session ID is getting wiped out, but I am positive the confirm call is affecting my session somehow.

Comment: haha! To be fair the confirm call is messing with the browsers ability to read the session ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, here's the solution, if you are running Safari 5.0.5 UPDATE NOW! 5.0.5 is junk. Call this a coincidence but for me this has reenforced the age long cliche about Apples inability to develop good software.